# Using javascript variables in html

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I could not succeed how to use javascript variables in html. At the bottom of the code I wanted to show images with dynnamic paths. But it doesnt work. When I write I searched but the answers were not my cure.  Thanks in advance.

```
<a href="#"><script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<img src="./images/bird.gif" name="img0" id="img0" onclick="javascript:fnChangeBorder(0);return false;"></a>')</script>
```

it works but not when i write

```
<a href="#"><script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<img src="'+imagelink0+'" name="img0" id="img0" onclick="javascript:fnChangeBorder(0);return false;"></a>')</script>
```

I am not good at javascript. So Can you be a little bit simpler while explaining. Here is all the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


<body>
<style>
.greenClass {
    border: 3px solid #FFCC66;
    filter: opacity(30%);
}
.redClass {
    border: 3px solid #FF0000;
    filter:opacity(30%);
}

</style>

<!-- What I want to do is play random animal sound and show random 4 animal images. 
The user listens the animal sound and then chooses the correct animal image.
 If the user clicks the  correct image then the border of the image changes to green otherwise to red.
"sample3.mp3" has animal sounds in every 2 seconds.  0-2 seconds has bee sound, 2-4 seconds has dog sound, 4-6 seconds has cat sound ....
imgarr array has animal names the same order with imgSounds.
The problem that when I directly write the image path below, it works but when I write a dynamic path like in the next image below the images are not there.


-->

<audio id="sample" preload controls>
    <source src="sample3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    Sorry
</audio> 
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>


<script>
var audio = document.getElementById('sample');  
var segmentEnd;
var imgSounds = [0,2,4,6,8,10];  // Every sound has 2 seconds length (bee sound, dog sound, cat sound ...). In every 2 seconds a different sound starts. All in one mp3 file.
var imgarr = ["bee","dog","cat","donkey","lion","bird"]; // image names are stored in an array.
var shuffledSounds;
var imagelink0; // This is variable keeps the dynamic link path > document.write('<img src="'+imagelink0+'" name="img0" id="img0" onclick="javascript:fnChangeBorder(0);return false;"></a>')  
var imagelink1;
var imagelink2;
var imagelink3;

function myFunction() {
audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (){
    if (segmentEnd && audio.currentTime.toFixed() >= segmentEnd) {
        audio.pause();
    }   
}, false);

var shuffledSounds = imgSounds.slice();
shuffle(shuffledSounds);
imagelink0= "./images/"+imgarr[0]+".gif";
imagelink1= "./images/"+imgarr[1]+".gif";
imagelink2= "./images/"+imgarr[2]+".gif";
imagelink3= "./images/"+imgarr[3]+".gif";

 // when shuffled the first item in the array has the random animal sound. 
 // I mean that if   shuffledSounds[0] is 4 then   audio player goes to 4. second and plays the animal sound.
playSegment(shuffledSounds[0]);  

function playSegment(startTime){
    segmentEnd = startTime+2;
    audio.currentTime = startTime;
    audio.play();
}
}




function shuffle(mixArray) {
  var currentIndex = mixArray.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = mixArray[currentIndex];
    mixArray[currentIndex] = mixArray[randomIndex];
    mixArray[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  return mixArray;
}



function fnChangeBorder(imgID){ // Change border if correct image is clicked 
if (imgID == 0) {
document.getElementById("img0").className = "greenClass";
}  else {
document.getElementById("img1").className = "redClass";
document.getElementById("img2").className = "redClass";
document.getElementById("img3").className = "redClass";
}

}

</script>

<!--The problem is here. When I directly write the image path below, it works but when I write a dynamic path, the images are not there.
one more thing: how can i show randomly  4 images one of which is the correct one.
-->

<a href="#"><script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<img src="'+imagelink0+'" name="img0" id="img0" onclick="javascript:fnChangeBorder(0);return false;"></a>')</script>
<a href="#"><script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<img src="'+imagelink1+'" name="img1" id="img1" onclick="javascript:fnChangeBorder(1);return false;"></a>')</script>
<a href="#"><script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<img src="'+imagelink2+'" name="img2" id="img2" onclick="javascript:fnChangeBorder(2);return false;"></a>')</script>
<a href="#"><script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<img src="'+imagelink3+'" name="img3" id="img3" onclick="javascript:fnChangeBorder(3);return false;"></a>')</script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: You'd be better off placing 4 HTML image tags with IDs at the bottom of your html, and then accessing them by ID all from the same javascript file. At present your variables (`imagelink0` etc..) are existing in a different scope to where you're writing the image tags..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to your problem is, when the variables are set to their value and when they are used. Most probably, this order is wrong. A simple solution would be to place the JavaScript code which sets the variables above the `document.write` lines. However, this only solves part of the problem: the images wouldn't change if you change your variables.

To achieve this, you need to change the `src` attribute of your `<img>` Tags every time one of your variables change their value.

So, instead of using `document.write()` you should place a static `<img>` Tag in your html code, give it an `id` attribute and access it via JavaScript like that:

```
var img = document.getElementById("#img-id");
function changeImgPath(newPath) {
    img.src = newPath;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean:     var img = document.getElementById("img0");
function changeImgPath(newPath) {
    img.src = newPath;
}
changeImgPath("./images/bird.gif");    <a href="#"><img src="" name="img0" id="img0" onclick="javascript:fnChangeBorder(0);return false;"></a>

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Only that you need to place your html in the html part and the javascript somewhere else (in between `<script>` tags).